# error with submitting a form in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i've created a plugin (simple form) and this is the shortcode.php file:

```
<?php
add_shortcode('contact_form','contact_form');

function contact_form(){
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $data = array('name'=>$name,'message'=>'message');
        $wpdb->insert($table_prefix.'contact_form',$data,array('%s','%s'));
        echo 'added';
    }

    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="" id="contact_form">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
<?php
}
```

when I submit the form, if I write sth in the text field, is says 'The page doesn't exist' but if i leave it empty, it submits the form.
what is the problem?
I have used this shortcode in a page.

Comment: Did you add a reference to `action` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184728/404-on-form-submit) on the WordPress StackExchange site.  In summary, WordPress gets confused by a field called `name`.  Try renaming it to (say) `contact_name`.

Loads more detail [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77337/page-returns-404-with-post-variables-but-not-without) (also wpse).